# How to show product custom attribute to invoice email in magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2

I want to show product custom attribute below the product image and SKU to invoice email in magento2.2.0?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml**

This is my registration.php file
**app/code/Amy/InvoiceEmailPcb/registration.php**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amy_InvoiceEmailPcb" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

This is my module.xml file
**app/code/Amy/InvoiceEmailPcb/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amy_InvoiceEmailPcb" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

This is my sales_email_order_invoice_renderers.xml
**app/code/Amy/InvoiceEmailPcb/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_invoice_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" as="default" template="Amy_InvoiceEmailPcb::email/items/invoice/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is my default.phtml
**app/code/Amy/InvoiceEmailPcb/view/frontend/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getItem()->getOrder(); ?>

<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($_item->getProductId());
?>

<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl>
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item->getOrderItem())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php //Your code starts to show custom attribute value ?>
    <dl class="item-options">
        <dt><?= __('PCB Master') ?>:</dt>
        <dd><?php echo $product->getData('pcb_master'); ?></dd>
    </dl>
    <?php //Your code ends to show custom attribute value ?>

        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQty() * 1 ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: but this solution depends on saving the custom attribute also to order and invoice datamodels, not?

Comment: I did this on theme level and it worked. Thank you.